# how to parse or read Int from BufferedReader?

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm trying to read an int with `BufferedReader`. I know i have a mismatch with the type (string, int) but i not sure what i need to change about the code to make it work.

I know how to use it for string reading and printing but no for int and use some operators

```
import java.io.*;
public class tmetodoI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader 
            (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    String num = "";    
        
        System.out.print("Ingrese un valor entero para determinar si es multiplo de 6");
        
        try {
        num = dataIn.readLine();        
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Error!");
        }
        
        if (num%6>0)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `Scanner`?

Answer (score 0):

You convert your string into int using
Integer.parseInt(num);

To convert into other primitive data types have a look at

[parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

[parseFloat()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String))

[parseLong()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String))

[parseDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Answer (score -2):

you can use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert `String` to `int`, use following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String num = "";

    System.out.print("Ingrese un valor entero para determinar si es multiplo de 6");

    try {
        num = dataIn.readLine();

        if (Integer.parseInt(num)%6 > 0) {
            System.out.println("inside condition");
        } else {
            System.out.println("out of the condition");
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.print("Error!");
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not correct or acceptable to catch exceptions and then proceed as though they hadn't happened. Don't write code like this.